# How to upgrade VirtualBox to the latest version?

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, virtualbox

I am currently using VirtualBox 3.2. I would like to upgrade it to latest version without losing any operating systems in it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Head on over to [this](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) page and download the Ubuntu package for your version / architecture.

Be sure to get the [VirtualBox extension pack](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.0.2/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.0.2-69518.vbox-extpack) too. (This provides USB 2.0 and RDP support.) The most recent version can be found on the [VirtualBox Downloads page](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: +1 From experience I know that you won't loose your Virtual Machines when you do this

Comment: I can confirm this. VBox 3.2 needs to be removed before installing 4.0 but you will not loose any vdi :)

Comment: i can also confirm this. I have upgraded to virtualbox 4 yesterday. working fine with compiz.

Comment: The link to the VirtualBox extension pack is outdated. The current version is 4.0.2 which can be found at http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: @Lek: You can edit my answer.

Comment: @George Edison: Done :)

Answer (score 8):

Add one line to your /etc/apt/sources.list:

> deb
>   http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian
>   maverick contrib

The Oracle public key for apt-secure can be downloaded [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc). You can add this key with

```
wget -q http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

To install VirtualBox, do

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-4.0
```

Comment: It's better to add the repo if you can. I have updated my own machine without problems.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to upgrade virtualbox from the ppa available from virtualbox directly.

There is also a good ppa if you want to make sure you keep the open source edition (ose):

https://launchpad.net/~debfx/+archive/virtualbox

Comment: broken links, -1

Comment: You could have just asked me to fix it.

Comment: +1 Or easier still, just edit the answer with the new link...

Comment: Tom: not sure Henrik could edit the answer.

Comment: @MartinOwens-doctormo- Anyone can suggest an edit. Even unauthenticated people.