# Can't find external CD/DVD in Virtual Box/Windows XP mode?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, dvd, cd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up USB for Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

If this is the wrong forum I apologize. As I mentioned in another Question, I am new to Linux but will never go back to Windows!

The internal CD/DVD on my Dell Studio 15 laptop died (gee what a surprise!). So I purchased a Dell external CD/DVD W/R 8X optical drive. It is cool in that it connects via two USB's that consolidate to one connector to the retractable on the Drive......no power cord.

Anyway, when I am in Ubuntu I can see the drive. But when I am VB/Windows XP I can find it. Under Computer it only shows the internal 'dead' one.  The friend who set this up for see up a number of 'outlets' but each time I press one I get 'connection not established'.

I can 'see' the two USB Flash drives in Windows/VB that I can easily access in Ubuntu.

What am I 'not seeing' (pardon the late night east coast humor).  And thanks if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Your computer icon inside Windows will show only the virtual hardware that you have created on your virtual machine, not your real one. By default, all virtual machines are created with only one CD driver.

But you can assign any of your real drives to this one, even just iso images. You can righ click on the CD icon on the bottom rigth of the screen or use the Device Menus to do this. If you are using the seamless mode, you will find the menu on the bottom bar.

In the following screenshot sr0 is an external USB drive.

[image]