# how to setup wps on xerox phaser 3020?

Tags: printing, xerox

So I have a new xerox phaser 3020. I was told it supports Linux.

Indeed - connecting it to the laptop with USB works like a charm. I am able to print.

However, this printer is also wireless. But I can't seem to be able to setup the wireless configuration.

I got a disc, but the disc only has software for mac/windows. 
How do I do the same with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything related, but faced the same problem and found the awkward solution (but it works). You can configure it using virtuabox with USB 2.0 driver + windows 7 image. Here is how:

1. Install virtualbox from synaptic.
2. Download virtualbox extension pack from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), however you'll probably need to install older version for your ubuntu. You will find it [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0) and [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing) are installation instructions.
3. Now it's the funny part, I have few old virtualbox windowses for development, which are perfectly legal and freely available from microsoft [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/).
4. I used windows 7 version and it works, but to enable USB 2.0 and to add your device connected to host machine, you need to [add your user to vboxusers group](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48982/how-can-i-connect-usb-printer-in-virtual-box-ose-win-xp/98838#98838). Don't forget to reboot afterwards.
5. Having everything set up you may configure USB 2.0 for you virtualbox device and add your printer. I made a small screenshot how to do it:

[image: USB 2.0 setup in VirtualBox]

6. Install xerox drivers and finally configure WIFI network for your printer.
7. Assign static IP to the printer on your router, remove whole s**t above and enjoy the WIFI printer from your linux network.

This HOWTO probably works with any cheap WIFI printer devoid of UI and with networking intended to be setup only from windows :)