# How to activate VirtualBox USB devices support?

Tags: usb, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up USB for Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

Using Ubuntu 11.10, downloaded Virtual Box from software centre plus extension pack.
Have added my user name to Vboxusers group.

When trying to add a usb filter VirtualBox insists there are no USB devices available.
Want to access my iPod via iTunes on a Windows XP guest.

How do I get VirtualBox to see my USB and allow my guest to use it?

Comment: Have You installed Guest additions on Your guest OS?

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41478/how-do-i-install-the-closed-source-version-of-virtualbox

Answer (score 2):

The package virtualbox-ose available in the repositories does not include support for USB.

You will need to uninstall that and get the version from Oracle. 
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads