# Guest additions installed but USB devices can't be seen in Devices > USB

Tags: 11.10, usb, virtualbox, usb-drive, guest-additions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up USB for Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

I already installed guest additions for VirtualBox but I can't see my USB flash from VirtualBox device list.

Please help me.