# Nokia 5800 is not recognized in Win7 virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up USB for Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

I've just installed win7 in ubuntu, and I'd like to connect my phone and use it in Win7. When the phone is connected, nothing happens in the win7 virtual box. How come it wont recognize it?

Thanks.

Comment: enable USB access in virtualbox if you have done that then consult the makers of Windows 7

Comment: SOLVED: I actually installed the version of the virtual box from the Software Centre....while the version from the virtualbox.org site is needed for USB support. I also had to follow the steps recommended by Achu here (to add myself to the virtualbox users group): http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Comment: could you post your comment as an answer and accept it please, to mark the question solved.

Comment: @Daniel I have no idea how to do that....I am new here. I'll figure it out ASAP.

Comment: yeah it's kind of weird...cause you can't accept your own answers until you have earned a certain amount of reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: I actually installed the version of the virtual box from the Software Centre....while the version from the virtualbox.org site is needed for USB support (make sure there you choose linux and the appropriate kernel architecture (here is the link to the download site: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

I also had to follow the steps recommended by @Achu here (to add myself to the virtualbox users group): askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

This should do the magic and help you set up your virtual box with working USB connections.
Good luck.