# USB drive on Ubuntu on VM Virtualbox

Tags: usb, virtualbox

OS X is my host OS.

I have windows xp and Ubuntu 10.10 on guest OS. They both work great. 
When I eject USB flash drive from host OS, it appears in windows guest OS 
but it does not appear in Ubuntu Guest OS.

I never run both guest OS at the same time. It's always either or.

I am running, VM VirtualBox 4.1.10 and installed latest guest additions and also installed VM virtualbox extension pack.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Answer (score 1):

If it's a USB 2.0 device you will need to enable it in each Virtualbox image.
Make sure that your USB settings for the Ubuntu guest OS is similar to the following:

[image]

Comment: thats exactly how enabled, I don't have a screen shot handy to post. Still guest ubuntu does not show the usb flash drive. however windows guest OS shows. so I don't it did set up correctly in the host OS VM

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Comment: tachyons - I added the user group as described in this post but still it does not work. I don't know whats the problem is