# USB not recognized in Virtualbox - Ubuntu 12.04 Host - Windows 7 Guest

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 12.04 host and cannot detect usb devices on windows 7 guest on virtualbox (guest-addon is installed), though  I configured vboxusers group and enabled it for my user account and still cannot detect any device :(

Comment: Do you have anything plugged in to USB?

Comment: have you tried setting exclusive access via the menu (of the running machine) Devices->USB Devices and then clicking on the specific device (if listed)?

Comment: Did you follow this: http://askubuntu.com/a/25600/3940?

Comment: OP has not signed on in 5+ years 1 day after posting this unanswered question about Ubuntu 12.04 which is now EOL. OP never replied to comments posted by @Takkat so VTC'ing as `not reproducible`.