# How can I get my HID device working in VirtualBox?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, windows-8, usbhid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up USB for Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

I'm running the latest official Ubuntu build of VirtualBox (4.1.12), with Windows 8 running as the guest OS.  I have a Windows app that works with a card reading HID device, but it's not detected by the guest OS at all.

I've installed the USB extensions, guest additions and set my `udev` rules accordingly (my own linux app is able to access the device), but no joy.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

Comment: It works on a standard Windows 8 machine just fine, I'm pretty sure  the guest OS doesn't make a difference. I'm not registered on the VirtualBox forums and, quite frankly, find forums to be slow when asking for support and not usually worth the hassle of signing up. Being the Ubuntu build of VirtualBox (4.1.12_ubuntu), I'm fairly sure this is question is perfectly valid here.

Comment: More importantly is it just this device or is it all devices? Could you try passing through something like a printer? (And this is probably on-topic)

Comment: And see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Comment: @Oli: that was the solution, I guess you can go ahead and close this as a dupe. Thanks very much.