# virtualbox usb problem

Tags: virtualbox

How can I use a usb stick in the virtual machine ? When I opened 'settings', a warning opened by itself and said that I had to add my user to the group vboxusers. I did that (sudo adduser naomi vboxusers), but the warning is still displayed, and the usb stick is still not recognized by the VM, although it is by the host. If I click 'add' on the 'usb' tab of the settings, it says 'no device available'.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up USB for Virtualbox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems you have the wrong command, the correct one is in the  [VirtualBox Documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idp11545232)

sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username

(Where username is the user you want to add)

There you go, after you do that all you need to do is open Vbox and select Devices > USB > "Whatever usb device you want to add"

Comment: Okay, how can I undo the command I used then?

Comment: Well in either case I tried this command too, and usb still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you installed the "Oracle VM Virtualbox extension pack" in the correct version? It should work (at least works for me). Is the group vboxusers displayed when you type `groups` in a terminal? You have to logout and back in after adding a group btw.

Comment: Yes sorry, I hadn't logged out yet.