# How to use a USB drive on My virtual machine XP when I'm using ubuntu as the Host

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up USB for Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

I'm using Ubuntu as my Host and i've setup Windows Xp as my Guest Os using virtualBox.
But the Pendrives i insert In my Laptop are loaded in the HOST Ubuntu and not in the Guest OS.

How can i solve this problem please help.

Answer (score 0):

vboxusers group must be added to the user, and USB must be added via virtualbox->Settings->USB (http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to enable the device from within the guest OS. With the guest OS running, choose "Devices/USB devices" from the menu and select the USB device that you want to be mounted in your guest.