# Virtualbox - how to passthrough modem from ubuntu host to windows guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, usb-modem

It is possible to pass-through an usb modem which is not recognized by the host Ubuntu 15.04 to a windows guest?, I have the windows drivers and I want to use dial-up while keeping my Ubuntu host. How can I do that?, any other Virtualization software will allow me to do the trick?

Comment: Is your modem listed when running `lsusb` on the host?

Comment: Yes it gets listed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pass trough an USB device from host to guest in Virtual Box we need the following prerequisites (also see [this question & answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)):

- Install the Oracle Extension Pack for USB 2.0 support.
- Become a member of the group `vboxusers`.
- Activate USB support in the Virtual Box Manager.
- Select the host-device to be captured by the guest.

Sometimes an USB device may be recognized by the host but can not be captured with steps above. For these devices we may have more luck to set up an [USB device filter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209950/integrated-webcam-cannot-be-used-in-virtualbox-guest-xp). There may still be devices that can not be added. These devices may then not be supported, and unfortunately can't be used.

An USB device filter can be added with the Virtual Box Manager on selecting <kbd>+</kbd> in the USB device filter section (also see link above). Any device matching an entry in these filter settings will then be captured by the virtual machine on start-up.

To list possible entries for a filter we may also issue:

```
VBoxManage list usbhost
```

This command will list all available and recognized USB devices.

As a minimum a vendorID and the productID is recommended for an USB filter. These can also be listed and read with

```
lsusb -v
```

In rare cases a virtual machine will not be able to boot after we had attached a device by a filter. Then we can not use this device in a virtual machine.