# virtualbox and ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set up USB for Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

ok im having some tough times here and could use some guidence.
I have my laptop running ubuntu 12.10 and i installed Oracle VirtualBox and windows 7 within it.
I cant seem to get any of my USB devices to showup or work in the Virtual box.
Also, my Virtualbox doesnt connect to the internet at all.
I have updated my VB and installed all the addons i could find.

im new to running a VB so please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you try all of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox?

Comment: Have a look at the linked duplicate and its answers.  If USB 2.0 functionality is important then you should really be looking at the PUEL version available from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the version of Virtualbox in the repos for 12.10, in order to get networking to work navigate to network settings of the VM and select "Bridged Adapter" in the drop down.

Think its down to a change in network manager and will hopefully get fixed soon.

Similarly with USB devices make sure you enable the USB in the VM settings the, attached devices should then become visible in the status bar by clicking the little USB icon

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'mount' the USB devices in VirtualBox to Ubuntu. I can't give you instructions, as I don't have VirtualBox installed (I use VMWare Player), but it should be in the context menu. Something similar should be for networking.

Answer (score 0):

For the USB support in the USB virtualbox menu enable the checkboxes eventually, add the USB device by clicking the right symbol, also consider to install guest additions.

Here is what ive read:

h ttp://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/

h ttp://www.howtogeek.com/howto/31726/mount-usb-devices-in-virtualbox-with-ubuntu/

NAT internet should work as i know, at least with guest additions installed, i never run into problems with that.