# How to Create Virtual USBs on Ubuntu host connected to machines in virtualbox

Tags: server, usb, virtualbox, virtualization

I have to perform backup operations between servers .
my servers are virtual machines in Virtual Box .
What I want to do is to plug a usb in each server .
servers are virtual machines so usb drivers are virtual also .

Two steps to do :
1- I want to create virtual USB drivers on my Ubuntu host
2- Then I want to connect every virtual machine in the virualbox to one of those virtual usb drivers for copying things between those servers (machines) .

I found second step in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)
but couldn't find first step or anything similar ! 
Does anybody know how to create virtual usb ?
Does it need a special software of just can be made via command line .
I found this [link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/) tell how to make a virtual image but in windows :(

Comment: please help I can't believe that all http://askubuntu.com members don't know the answer of this question ! virtual usb on Ubuntu ! virtual image, virtual usb, usb emulator software anything may let me see many usbs in my laptop :D

Comment: Maybe there is no answer. AFAIK Virtualbox can't do that.

Comment: What do you mean by AFAIK ?

Comment: can't believe there's no way to add a virtual usb to linux :D

Comment: As Far As I Know. There is no way that I know to connect a virtual usb connected hard disk to a VirtualBox machine, in linux or in Windows. I don't know what you mean with "no way to add a virtual usb to linux".

Comment: @JavierRivera I hope I found it in here http://low-level-world.com/index.html
please tell me how to install it I'm a very new linux user

Comment: there's no hard disk mentioned in my question !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?. The file in your link is just an archive, uncompressing it and double clicking on installer.sh should work.

Comment: I did that but it didn't work , readme file says that I have to compaile src code before installing install.sh !!

Comment: I want to create virtual flashes on my device .

Comment: http://blog.mybox.ro/2010/11/03/how-to-use-a-raw-disk-image-file-in-virtualbox/#comment-8385

Comment: this link helps a little tell how to convert a usb image to format can be understood by virtualbox .

Comment: still need to know how to make an image for usb

Comment: Please don't add so many comments to your question. The site is not fit for this. Instead, invest time in improving your question and time in the site to gain enough reputation to be able to put a bounty on it.  :)

Comment: I'm sorry I was nervous :$ , I've edited my question .hope it's more clear now . i'm still looking for a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally me and a friend came across a solution for this problem .
we add a virtual hard disk to the machine and yes ! 
it's working now :D