# Virtual Machine Windows 7 USB webcam connection lost when switching back to Ubuntu

Tags: usb, windows-7, virtualbox, xubuntu, webcam

I am relatively new to Ubuntu, willing to learn, but don't have a ton of experience with command line interfaces (so go easy on me please if possible tech-wise!)...

I have xubuntu installed on my home computer, and recently installed VMWare Virtualbox, with which I created a virtual machine running windows 7, so I could run postureminder software (which accesses my usb webcam).

The software works fine when my 'focus' is on the virtualbox (i.e. the mouse/keyboard is inside the virtual machine) (I joined the vboxuser system group in ubuntu to enable this), but when I switch back to xubuntu the postureminder software does not registered me as being at the computer for the period I have worked in Xubuntu.

The only indication of a problem is that the software says 'welcome back' and has no record of my being at the computer for the period I work in xubuntu. Whether this is because the usb connection has been lost, or for some other reason I am not sure... I assume the virtual machine can run 'in the background' whilst I go back to working in ubuntu, so am guessing that it is something to do with the USB connection, hence me posting here, but realise it may be a VMWare or postureminder issue.

Thanks in advance for any help - much appreciated.

Ron

Comment: I haven't used virtualbox since the [kvm] has matured somewhat and would recommend to try it too. Secondly, the software might think that since you do not do any keyboard mouse movements in windows, that you are indeed away from keyboard or monitor the screen saver for that purpose. Maybe you can configure this there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can not help you on issues from your Windows software, and how this software may deactivate your webcam when it thinks you are away from keyboard.

It may however be worth to [install the Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox) to allow a much better desktop integration of the guest Windows with the host Ubuntu. Also read [this question and answers here on USB integration with Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox). You may want to try out if a USB filter gives you a better result, but I doubt it will change much.

USB devices routed to the guest OS will be deactivated from host access. However as soon as you terminate your virtual machine any USB device routed to the VM will be released again.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I am sure I have everything covered as per your USB integration with virtual Box link, and am now in the process of installing guest additions to try. If all Ubuntu does is release the USB device until I terminate the virtual machine, then I will have to look elsewhere, however your help has narrowed down the search, so thanks.