# How to use Virtual-Box / Unsuported USB Hardware / US144 in Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, hardware

Is it is possible to forward hardware, which Ubuntu doesnt support?

In my case I want to use a Tascam US-144 audio interface into a VM (which contains Windows) where the hardware can be recognized and used.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You will need to install the closed source [extension pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and [add](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) your user to the *vboxusers* group.

I do it quite often to run programs protected by hardware keys that connect to usb machines. Linux doesn't support either the key or the machine (although the machine is probably using a simple usb-serial port emulation). It works nicely with a Windows XP host.