# VirtualBox USB Problem with Windows 7 (64-bit) Guest

Tags: windows-7, usb-drive

I'm running VirtualBox 4.2.16_Ubuntu r86992 on Ubuntu 13.10 host.  The guest OS is Windows 7 (64-bit).  I have enabled USB controller and found the host USB devices (hard drive and memory stick).  I have also added my username to the vboxusers group (and rebooted).  However, the guest OS Windows 7 doesn't see the devices.  Windows 7 could not install device driver software when I attempted to fix the hardware.  I have also tried to install the extension pack but there seems to be no compatible version for 4.2.16.

Comment: Here's the extension pack: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2.16/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2.16-86992.vbox-extpack. For USB, did you see this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox? You should also consider updating Virtual Box to a newer release, your virtual machines will not be touched by this.

Comment: Works exactly when the extension pack is installed.  Thank you!

Comment: Here is a new and quick method to install usb drives http://www.uthweb.com/how-to/install-usb-device-drivers-for-virtualbox-on-ubuntu/