# Problem adding Printer to Virtual machine

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, printing, virtual-printer

I'm running 12.04 64 bit on my laptop and I have a virtual machine (win7) created and using with virtual box (4.3.6 incl. extension pack).

Further I have an Kyocera FS-1041 printer which I cannot use with linux cause of incompatibility with GDI.

Is there a way to tunnel the printer to my virtual machine and printing there? I already tried some filters for usb in virtual box but I failed.

Any ideas how to solve this problem using a virtual machine?

Comment: Is the printer recognized as an USB device in Ubuntu at all (`lsusb`)? For USB see also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks that was the problem, my user wasn't in the `vboxusers` group. After fixing that and some reboots of the virtual machine it worked.