# What options do you recommend for running an emulation of the Windows 7 operating system on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, virtualization, emulation

I realize there are several available but am unsure which are capable of running the Windows 7 OS in a virtual machine.

Comment: here's useful info https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualMachines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) often does a very good job - you can even [get it to work with hardware accelaration](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/enable-windows-7-aero-effects-virtualbox/):

[image: Windows desktop screenshot]

You can also [set up USB support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/set-up-usb-for-virtualbox).