# Anyway to get Brawlhalla(a windows only steam game) to run on Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, steam

I've looked around but I'm still unable to get it working. If anyone could help that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It is a possible duplicate of a previous [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/428376/442165). Use Wine as a windows emulator to run windows applications. Also take a look at this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/316025/442165).