# Ubuntu VM does not detect external disk attached to host.

Tags: virtualbox, external-hdd

I have install Ubuntu on VM using this guide - http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-on-VirtualBox

Install went O.K - and it's working 
but when I connect an external hard disk - it's won't show me it.
I have try to connect it before I run the VM, and also after the system is up -
nothing 
What can I do? 
Am I missing anything? Didn't install correctly?

Comment: Have you added the USB port to the virtual hardware available to the VM?

Comment: For an USB drive see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Comment: how do I know if I added the USB port to the virtual hardware available to the VM?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.htpcbeginner.com/access-usb-drive-in-virtualbox-guest-os/

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you have Guest Additions are installed.  Then, make sure that USB is enabled, and that the USB device is connected to the VM.  See images below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have install it , the USB is enable (like shown in the image).. and when I go to Devices-USB - I have only "No USB Devices Connected" ...   maybe there is a driver or something I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Then try mounting it with

```
sudo mkdir /media/my_usb_drive

sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb /media/my_usb_drive
```

ps: ntfs, and sdb are just example, you'll be able to find info related to your disk by reading the fdisk output

Comment: this is what I get Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1044 cylinders, total 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000bb1a2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    14680063     7339008   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        14682110    16775167     1046529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        14682112    16775167     1046528   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Answer (score 0):

Try installing **VirtualBox extension pack** based on your **VB** version from [this link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).
After that you can see your external hard USB port in VB **setting**.

> VirtualBox Setting --> USB

Answer (score -1):

1. I think I have install  Guest Additions  , how can I be sure?
   do I need to run something ? I have press "VBOXLinuxAdditions.run" . it open a window , and that it.
2. I don't an option to choose USB in the VM

I can't upload images so I can't show you screenshot