# Virtualbox does not detect USB-Stick

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and just installed the latest Virtualbox 4.3 to use Windows 7.
As explained here : [Set up Usb-stick for Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) ; I added myself to the vboxusers and also installed the extension pack.

However I still cannot make VirtualBox to detect any of my sticks, in order to add it to the filter list in the VM settings.
There is still no Virtualbox version for 14.04, may this be an issue?

Comment: Having the same issue...

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest version? With 4.3.12 Ubuntu 14.04 is supported: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Yep, pretty sure. But haven't seen then that it supports 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

I know this was several months ago, but it comes up as about the first google result.

I bet you it's the classic issue that you need to add your user to the vboxusers group.
If it isn't, it needs to be, add it, log out and back in again and it should work.

Comment: Thx for the help buddy! I remeber that I added myself to the vboxusers group. I havent used it for a few months but recently i needed it and somehow it worked^^

Comment: @guntbert : It wasn't really helpful to solve the problem( i have tried to add myself to the vboxusers group before posting this question)  i simply thanked him for trying to help on such an old question/problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the virtualbox extensions?

In order to get virtual box to detect USBs you will need to install the extensions.