# How to properly enable usb support on virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

How to enable the usb support on virtualbox properly ? I've just enabled it like the below screenshot shows (Iomega Select HDD), but, my windows 7 virtual machine wouldn't detect the usb. What's wrong please and how to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Install Guest Additions

After into in the Guest OS, go to `Devices` > `Install Guest Additions`:

[image]

The Guest Additions wizard will popup. Just follow the Next, Next until Finish.

Shutdown your guest.

### 2. Optional: Create a USB filter

You can create a filter to have your device automatically connected when our VM starts. **Just a reminder that this filter will make the device available for the guest VM AND PROBABLY NOT AVAILABLE for the host every time your VM is running**.

Example: I created a filter for my webcam. So, always I start my VM, the host will not able to use my webcam.

If you want this: open VirtualBox, select your VirtualMachine, right click and select `Settings`.

Go to the `USB` section.

Check if both `USB` options are enabled.

Then, click in the **second** button at right - the one with a **plus** sign and this title: `Adds a new USB filter with all fields set to the values of the selected USB device attached to the host PC`.

After click on it, it'll display all your host devices available to this system:

[image]

Select the one you want and this will create a USB filter for your device. Every time you start the VM, the device will be automatically shared to the VM.

Start your VM and check if it's working.

Comment: Downvote: You don't need to create a filter for a basic setup.

Comment: @javier-rivera: A comment should be enough, not a downvote. And, at least with my webcam and most of my USB devices, I need a filter. I preferred add this additional info than miss in my answer.

Comment: Filters don't change the supported devices, it just autoconnects them without needing to use the Device menu. It also disconnects them from linux and can create issues and confusion in users if they use a device in both oses. Your post implies that making a filter is needed, the second step for the solution. IMHO this is bad advice and deserves a downvote.

Comment: I didn't say the filter change the supported devices. And what users want IS the device in the VM when its started. I want my webcam always available in the VM when I start it. AND I MADE THIS CLEAR in the answer: the filter is to enable the VM always start with the device attached. It's your opinion and you're free to express it. You could use a comment without a downvote, but ok.

Comment: Now it's better, removed the downvote (and upvoted it).

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/virtualbox-usb.html) helped me.

It basically says to install the Guest Additions, add your user to the vboxusers group and that you need the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, and I found easier to add the user to the group like this: sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers {your user here}