# VirtualBox USB 'Add device filter` does not work under 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

﻿To make USB devices accessible to a guest OS under VirtualBox, one must

```
  i) install the appropriate extension pack 

 ii) navigate to 'Settings ----> USB' in the VirtualBox menu and

iii) tick 'Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller

 iv) add a `USB device filter`
```

Step iv) requires selecting a `USB device filter` by clicking on a list of available USB devices which appears at the mouse-pointer position

- when clicking on the 'Add new USB filter` icon on the right margin (
  a USB icon with a green plus sign )
- when pressing `ALT+INS`

  [image]

In either case one will see a list of USB device candidates currently attached to the host system.

[image]

These can then be selected and will appear permanently under the 'USB Device Filters' list of the USB menu.

[image]

This does not work under 14.04.

When attempting to add an attached device ( clicking on appropriate icon or pressing `ALT+INS` )

[image]

- VirtualBox can not see any of the connected USB devices, resulting in
  a `<no devices available>` message.
- Trying to enter the device details manually into a blankly created
  USB device filter does not work either.
- Booting the guest OS ( Win 7 ), you are not able to see any
  'removable drives'.

The obvious items were all checked:

- VirtualBox installed from repository ( apt-get install )
  App reports version 4.3.10
- Appropriate VirtualBox extension pack ( 4.3.1r93733 ) successfully downloaded+installed from the Oracle site

As mentioned previously on the the same box with 12.04 installed everything works as it should and Win7 can `see` the removable drive as expected.

As a last resort various permutations of VM settings, USB sticks, e.t.c. were tried without achieving the desired result.

- Has anyone encountered the same issue?
- Has anyone encountered similar difficulties?
- Has anyone been able to work around the problem? ( remember manual
  entry of device details into an empty filter entry has not worked )

Does anyone know if this is an issue

- with VirtualBox?
- with the current version of the VirtualBox extension pack?
- or perhaps even with Trusty Tahr itself?

I have full USB functionality on my 14.04 host.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You probably have a permission issue. Add your user ID to group `vboxusers` with this command: `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER`, log off, log on and try again.

Comment: That worked for me too on Ubuntu 14.04!

Comment: Worked for me on Mint 20.04. I also learned from this post that $USER (case-sensitive) resolves to my current User-ID - which will make it even easier in future for me to confidently Cut&Paste "solutions" like this. TY!

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above to no avail. I then tried a right mouse click over the USB filter area and found a menu choice "Add filter from device". Voila! It worked.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent last 6 hours trying to get my USB backup drive to work on my Ubuntu 14.04(host) with Win7Pro(guest).   Fortunately, I found one article from Tyler Durden(see link below) which mentioned incompatibility between older version of VirtualBox 4.3.10(downloaded from Ubuntu Software Center) and VirtualBox Extension Pack 4.3.14(downloaded from VirtualBox.org).

After re-installing with the new version of VirtualBox, so far everything appears to be working fine,  YMMV.

[How to set up USB for Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox/519042)