# Virtualbox - Vm can`t open usb

Tags: usb, virtualbox, windows-8

I have installed Windows 8 on Virtual Machine.

At first it could not recognize any USB 
I tried the solution in [How to set up USB for Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

and now the system can understand that I connected a removable disk.
Now there is another problem as you can see below:
[image]

What should I do?
I also installed VirtualBox Extension Pack.

One more thing, Windows can't recognize either my webcam even if it recognizes the bluetooth devices.

Comment: Are you sure that this device is working properly. Did you try with some other devices? Which version of Ubuntu and Virtual Machine are you using?

Comment: yes i tried usb2 and usb3, i`m using ubuntu 14.04 and vm version is 4.3.12

Comment: I mean did you try _another_ pen drive?

Comment: yes i did as i wrote i tried usb2 pendrives and usb3 pendrives

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure that you haven't mounted the USB stick in Ubuntu itself. Also, just in case, the latest version of VirtualBox is actually 4.3.14, which you might consider upgrading to.

But more likely, if you only enabled USB 2.0 *after* having installed Windows, you might have to remove and re-add the USB controller from the Windows Device Manager, as it may have originally detected and selected a driver which isn't actually appropriate. Of course, the Hail-Mary option is outright reinstalling Windows (perhaps to a new VM or at least a new snapshot) since sometimes that's faster than fiddling around with getting Windows to re-detect its hardware properly.

Comment: when vm is open and running windows USB unmounted automatically in Ubuntu maybe i should try re-install it again