# How to use USB bluetooth dongle/internal bluetooth chip on a virtual windows xp machine on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualbox, bluetooth, windows-xp

I am able to use my internal bluetooth chip on Ubuntu (obvious). But I can't use it in a virtual machine(Windows xp) installed with Virtualbox. I also have a USB bluetooth dongle. But the problem is that my virtual machine doesn't show any 'found new hardware' or similar thing in it's task bar.  FYI I have installed guest additions too, but I am still unable to get any USB device working with the virtual machine.

How can I use bluetooth in the virtual windows xp machine (with internal chip/ USB dongle)?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but here's a suggestion for anyone else who finds this post.

You said

> ... I am still unable to get any USB device working ...

which suggests you you need to add the user to virtualbox users with the command  `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers username` Then you need to activate USB support, disable support for the specific device(s) for the host OS and enable the device(s) for the guest OS. The first answer by Takkat in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) describes it well for different versions of virtual box.