# cannot access hard disk usb from virtualbox guest with winows 7 on ubuntu host

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox, windows-7, hard-drive

First of all sorry for my english :)

I'm using VirtualBox 4.3.18 (downloaded from oracle's site)
I'm running ubuntu 14.04 as host and windows 7 64bit as guest.
When i plug the usb hard disk the host recognizes it, but if i start the guest and i open the devices menu i can see the entry for the hd, but it's greyed out and appears as not available.

1. i've installed both extension pack and guest additions
2. in the machine settings i've checked: Enable USB controller and Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) cntroller
3. i've added the user to the `vboxusers` group with the command `sudo gpasswd -a nomeutente vboxusers`
4. i've tryed to plug the hd both before and after starting the guest without results
5. i.ve tryed to "safely remove" the drive and also to unmount it with the command `sudo umount /media/user/drivename`, but it still results not available.
6. i've tryed to create a USB Device Filter for the hd from the machine settings with the "plus" button, but no results, even retrying points 4 and 5

I have no more ideas, what can I try?
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Did you also reboot the guest after you made your settings?

Comment: @Takkat thanks for the tip, but I rebooted both the host and the guest several times without success

Comment: Please check again with `groups` whether you are a member of `vboxusers`. Also, the USB-drive has to be formatted as Windows compatible (NTFS, FAT32) - if that was not the case you can only access it via a network share. Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox

Comment: Oh - and the USB drive has to be mounted in Ubuntu first before it can be used from the VM (it will be automatically unmounted from the host while accessed from the guest).

Comment: @Takkat thank you again, but this not solve. - I checked with `group` and `id` and appears in the list the group `vboxusers` - the file system of the hard disk is NTFS - I looked at the link but I had already done all the steps - . i've tryed to plug the hd both before and after starting the guest without results - the only change is that now all the usb devices are not available, not just the hard drive