# Can't boot from USB Drive on VirtualBox machine

Tags: partitioning, usb, virtualbox

I know there are similar questions with a similar title but my situation is a bit different. I'm following this tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/ to resize my partition but Ubuntu is on a VirtualBox machine. I don't have enough room in my root hard drive, `/dev/sda/1` to download an .iso from my Ubuntu OS(the download is 1.1 GB; I only have 337 MB left), so I decided to download the ISO onto my Mac and I transferred the .iso to my USB drive. When I turned on the `Startup Disk Creator` on my Ubuntu virtual machine, there are no .iso images displayed.

Booting it from a CD isn't an option for me because in order to insert a CD into a Mac, I need a disk drive, which I don't have.

I am now stuck and confused on what to do now.

Comment: In the virtualbox settings panel for USB, you may need to add a filter to allow the virtual machine to see that USB drive.

Comment: Is that on my Ubuntu VM itself or the settings page you get that lists all of your VMs?

Comment: It would be in the virtualbox application that you run on the Mac (host). Choose the Ubuntu VM, then the USB tab.

Comment: How did you make the bootable USB (e.g. did you use [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)?)

Comment: Here's a page that shows what to do to see USB devices: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox  . I don't know whether this `vboxusers` group is required on the Mac, though.

Comment: Now something really weird is happening. After I updated my virtualbox and started the Ubuntu VM, I got the boot grub menu. I click `Ubuntu` and all I get is a bunch of green and blue colors on a messed up screen. What did I screw up?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think you can fix your problem.

Download Plop Boot Manager from [here](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanager/download.html) onto your computer with VirtualBox installed

Extract the zip file.

Open VirtualBox, select the your Virtual Machine, click on "Settings" (The Yellow Gear).

On the sidebar settings window, click storage. Under "Controller IDE" click the empty disk (or add one if there isn't any). Under attributes click the disk icon and select "Choose a Virtual CD/DVD File..."

Image:

[image]

Select to "plpbt.iso" in the files you extracted before.

Save any changes by pressing "OK"

Boot your virtual machine.

Plug in your USB drive

On the menu bar of VirtualBox, click "Device --> "USB Devices" --> your USB drive

Then in Plop boot manager select USB using your arrow keys.

The Virtual machine should now boot the Ubuntu installer from your USB drive if you installed it correctly. You should have installed it on the USB drive following [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) instructions.

**Source**: [How to Boot a VMware Virtual Machine from a USB Drive](http://www.howtogeek.com/97923/how-to-boot-a-vmware-virtual-machine-from-a-usb-drive/)