# How to get Ubuntu (running through VirtualBox) to detect my flash drive?

Tags: system-installation, usb, virtualbox, surface

I am on a Surface Pro 3. I want do a full install of Ubuntu on my flash drive. I

saw in a tutorial that it can be done by running Ubuntu from live cd mode. Since my Surface does not have a cd drive, I ran Live CD Mode in VirtualBox. Unfortunately, my USB Flash Drive does not get detected.

I am assuming this is essentially a VirtualBox issue and I was wondering if anyone has any experience with this? I can see my USB Drive listed in the ports but when I click on it nothing happens and it is not an option for installing when I click on install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This answer, ["How to set up USB for Virtualbox?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) seems to be a fairly complete description of the process.