# Unable to view/connect usb devices to a virtualbox guest from ubuntu host

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I'm trying to connect an NXT Robot to a windows XP guest in Virtualbox, I have installed virtualbox's Extension Pack. Not a single usb device shows up in virtual box, yet lsusb shows they are all connected to my host.

```
william@ubuntu-laptop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0694:0002 Lego Group Mindstorms NXT
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 049f:0051 Compaq Computer Corp. KU-0133 Easy Access Interner Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1c4f:0034 SiGma Micro 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c18 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

As you can see, my robot is connected on the first usb, yet nothing shows in Vbox, not even mouse and keyboard, is vbox hiding them by default since they not a storage device? (I have not tried connecting a usb key) I need to way to force Vbox to forward control of the device through the guest, where I can connect it to the RobotC IDE.

I installed Vbox through the software centre. It is version 4.3.26 (Latest, only installed it today)

Comment: Have you enabled the USB in VirualBox?

Comment: Enabled both USB Controller and USB 2.0 (EHUI) Controller. I haven't added any filter, so it should show everything, right?

Comment: try adding a filter, I find it doesn't show my webcam if it's not exclusive.

Comment: I tried adding a filter, still nothing. Tested my theory about only showing storage devices, nope, nothing. Reinstalled extension pack, and I'm getting sick of typing the n word but you get the idea. Maybe I should ask around at the vbox forum as well.

Comment: Yeah, VBoxer people may know more :/

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox - if all is set up correctly you should see USB devices such as USB keys, printers or the like. Test with these first and report if they failed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I had to be part of the "vboxuser" group. It is working now

Answer (score 23):

The problem was I wasn't part of the `vboxuser` group. For those with the same problem:

1. Make sure you have the Virtualbox Extension Pack. This allows use of USB 2.0. USB 3.0 is not yet supported.
2. Add yourself to the `vboxuser` group (in the host):

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers <useruame>
   ```
3. Log out then back in for the change to take effect.
4. Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) controller in the settings for you VM.

If you need more help see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox) topic.

Credit to Takkat.

Comment: You answer continues to help, even years later.  Thank you.  In my case, the vboxusers didn't appear until I rebooted my host.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after having applied William **Satterthwaite**'s hack above, I could see the list of USB devices in VirtualBox and connect them. But they wouldn't appear in the guest OS. Then I turned off the guest and change the USB adapter from USB 3.0 to USB 2.0. I rebooted the machine and had the USB device displayed in the guest OS.

Comment: If you are using windows 7, it does not support USB 3.0. Any support must be provided by motherboard drivers. In the case of virtualbox, you'll want [the driver for the device that virtualbox emulates](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/21129/USB-3-0-Driver-Intel-USB-3-0-eXtensible-Host-Controller-Driver-for-Intel-7-Series-C216-Chipset-Family)