# How can ubuntu recognize a barcode reader?

Tags: drivers, barcode

I have a Datalogic quickscan QD2430 barcode reader. It works perfectly on windows. How can I make it work in VM environment?
I disconnect the b/c reader from the host device to the VM,  but I get a warning on Ubuntu that there is a problem with the driver. When I type lsusb I can't see the b/c reader in the list.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure that you pass the usb port to the Virtual Machine. In Virtual Box, in the Device menu, under usb submenu make sure that the barcode appears and is checked.

If the device is grayed and you can't select it, please see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox).

Now the barcode should appear in the lsusb command. The easiest way to use it under Ubuntu is to put it in keyboard emulation, it's usually the default working configuration for a barcode reader but you can change it scanning a device dependent barcode (check the device manual).

Comment: I pass the usb port to the Virtual Machine. In the VM Menu Player>>Removable Devices>>Connect(disconnect from host). I do the same for the mouse and with the lsusb appears. The barcode scanner is not appearing. When I am in ubuntu, it gives a warning message that "THe connectoin for the USB device was unsuccesful.Driver error"

Comment: Did you put the barcode in "keyboard mode"?. Ubuntu probably lacks drivers to other modes.