# Windows 7 client on virtualbox Ubuntu 14.04 host, not recognizing USB stick

Tags: usb, virtualbox, windows-7

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 box running virtualbox 4.3.10 with the extension pack installed that goes with it. A Windows 7 client is running in virtualbox. It has 1 cpu assigned to it, if that matters. Inserting a USB stick is recognized in ubuntu, then I try to bring it up in Windows 7 by using the popup menus at the bottom of the client. The USB menu recognizes the USB stick and allows it to be checked. But windows 7 never mounts the USB stick. Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox - if all that worked it may also be an issue of the guest OS.

Comment: I think I have done that, as described in the link. The one difference I can see is that in the host virtualbox settings for USB, "Enable USB Controller" is checked but greyed out, and "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" is not checked and also greyed out. My USB stick is listed in the device filters list and it is checked.

Comment: Finally got it working. I shutdown the windows 7 client in powered off state. Then, the settings mentioned above were no longer greyed out. I was able to check the "Enable USB 2.0 (EHCI) Controller" and save it. Then the windows 7 client was started again and this time it recognized the USB stick.

Comment: Thank you for that valuable hint. Sometimes the obvious solution doesn't appear on top of the list. Edited my answer to the question above to help future visitors who may face the same problem.