# ubuntu can't turn on bluetooth

Tags: virtualbox, bluetooth

My computer is Mac air 
I install the virtualbox and had a ubuntu14.04 vm
But the vm can't turn on bluetooth on ubuntu

I install the `bluez`
I open the bluetooth on mac and add the setting on virtualbox
But nothing happened
How can I fix this ??

[image]

[image]

I got this error:

```
Failed to attach the USB device Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller [0106] to the virtual machine Ubuntu Test.

USB device 'Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller' with UUID {b1812d8b-2505-4a4c-9d34-bfbd73266cd2} is in use by someone else.

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: HostUSBDeviceWrap
Interface: IHostUSBDevice {c19073dd-cc7b-431b-98b2-951fda8eab89}
Callee: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Comment: Did you become a `vboxuser` group member (also see [my answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/25600/3940))? What do you get on `lsusb` in the ubuntu guest after capturing the device?

Comment: It said is in used by others

Comment: OSX may not be able to release the device. See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2372 for a possible solution (can't test if it still works due to an immense lack of Apple devices here).