# USB device not recognized

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I am using Qiime in VirtualBox 5.0.6. I am a begginner! I must start working with Qiime by having my fasta files in the directory and I want to do this by using a USB device. However, the VB doesn't recognize the device. Besides everything in Settings USB section appears in grey color. I have read everything in several forums but the information is confusing (adding user name to vbox group, sudo command, etc.).

Please, can someone explain to me, step by step, how to access to a USB device into the virtual machine?

Many thanks in advance.

Carolina

Comment: Did you also see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using shared folders? Then you can put the fasta files on your host machine and access them from both host and guest.

It would help us if you would specify what OS your host is (I am guessing Windows, but which? 7, 8, 10?), and the Ubuntu version on your VM.

Also make sure you have the Guest Additions installed.

Comment: Thanks Wil. I tried to do this but the installation of Guest Additions wasn't successful. I managed this issue by an USB device.