# how to detect the usb stick in Ubuntu installed in virtual box

Tags: usb

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 on VirtualBox in Windows 7. How can I detect the USB flash disk in Ubuntu.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox - did this help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a filter for it, and then unplug it and plug it in again. You can find more information on the process and examples in the following link:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idp46608643879360