# How open NTFS USB in Virtualbox using WIndows

Tags: usb, virtualbox, ntfs

My main computer is Ubuntu 15.10. I have virtualbox working properly and followed the steps in the following link so that the virtual Windows 10 can recognize USB devices: [How to set up USB for Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)

Although the virtual Windows10 can recognize my USB keyboard and mouse, it can't recognize my USB drive in NTFS format (I recently converted it to NTFS from FAT). How can I get the virtual Windows10 to recognize the NTFS USB?

Comment: Unfortunately Windows deliberately prevents you from using NTFS on USB sticks because it is a journalled filesystem and people will quickly corrupt their data with their penchant for not safely disconnecting it first.

To protect users from themselves, Windows will only provide support for a single FAT-formatted partition on USB sticks.

Comment: @JeffSereno: this should be an answer I guess.