# Passing unrecognized usb devices to virtualbox

Tags: usb, virtualbox, hardware

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 with all the updates and have Win 10 installed on Virtualbox. I can use usb devices in Win 10, like thumb drives, webcam and so on, so I know vbox has been set up correctly (guest additions, usb support etc).

My problem is that I want to update the firmware on my Vaporesso Target Pro, for which I need Windows. When I plug in the mod, I don't see it on the list with USB devices.

```
[11065.688847] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[11065.808894] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[11066.032890] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[11066.248827] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[11066.368888] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[11066.592897] usb 3-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71
[11066.808830] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[11066.809139] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[11067.013140] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[11067.216818] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 9, error -71
[11067.328838] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[11067.329157] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[11067.533146] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[11067.736829] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 10, error -71
```

That's what I get in dmesg when I plug it in, so now it makes sense that I don't see it in virtualbox. However, I have no idea how to get Ubuntu to recognize it so I can pass it through to virtualbox.

Comment: Did you try with an [USB filter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)?

Comment: I can only add a USB filter if I have the vendor ID. Because the device doesn't respond to setup address, it's not listed in lsusb list.
I assume because this device charges from USB as well as being firmware upgradeable and I think it draws too much power from my usb ports, hence the errors.

Comment: You can try on another USB-Port, or use an active USB hub, but for just a firmware upgrade this may not be safe enough. I am pretty confident that you will be able to borrow somebody's Windows machine ...

Answer (score -1):

In order to use your USB device on the guest system, all you should need is the USB vendor ID and product ID.  Plug your device in, and try the `lsusb` command, which shows "vendor ID:product ID" as hexidecimal numbers.  By doing `lsusb` when the device is plugged in and when it's not, you should be able to figure out which entry in the `lsusb` table belongs to your device.

Once you know the vendor ID and product ID, head over to VirtualBox and create a USB filter for it according to [the VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#idm1631).  Once you do that, the device should be visible to the guest OS.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but if you'd had read my question properly, you would've seen messages like "[11066.809139] usb 3-1: Device not responding to setup address."
lsusb does not give a VendorID, so I cannot set up a filter. If only it would be that simple, I would not have come to askubuntu :)

Comment: The USB device is a vaping mod. Linux apparently has a problem detecting it while on Windows it's automatically detected.
All I need from Linux is to allow me to connect it to my Windows VM so I can update the firmware.

Comment: How was I to know that "device not responding to setup address" meant that `lsusb` didn't return a vendor ID?  You didn't include the output of `lsusb` in your question.  What's with a downvote for someone who made a good-faith effort to help?

Comment: The downvote because you listed this as an answer/solution instead of a comment. If you wanted to know my lsusb output, then you should've asked in a comment for me to post it. You were assuming and you were wrong, that's why the downvote, it's nothing personal, just an indication that your answer is off and others looking for the same problem shouldn't be pursuing this route to find an answer.
Just google the error and you'll see there isn't going to be an lsusb output