# Unable to use USB in virtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm *new* to both Ubuntu and VirtualBox.
I've **already enabled USB controller** for *Windows 10 virtual machine*, But no devices are available when I click to "*add USB filter button*". So what should I do now?

Comment: Is it possible that the USB device is already connected to another VM running in parallel?

Comment: here I just mean that I've just  enabled Usb controller and when I click to add new USB filter no device is found.

Comment: Did you follw this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox? Any errors you get?

Comment: After downloading the extension pack from here ( https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads ), and rebooting, (then selecting "settings">USB>USB3.0),  the problem has finally solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must add your user the `vboxusers` group by doing:

`sudo usermod -G vboxusers -a <username>`

Or by edditing the `/etc/group` file with `nano`, or `vim`, and adding your user name in front of `vboxusers`:

Remember, you must do this in the host, not in the guest. Then logout and login again, or reboot your computer.

Aditya suggest: *The [extension pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) could be required*,

see the comments for details.

Comment: After entering it they are providing a tons of options I'm confused for what to select, as I'm a newbie

Comment: Remember to replace <username> with your username, for example:
sudo usermod -G vboxusers -a Aditya

Comment: Yes after replacing with my username It shows lots of options to select. few of those are: -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group

Comment: @Aditya It seems you're still not using (your) correct username.

Comment: Sorry for that, I actually had entered my name instead of user name. but even after correcting it I'm still unable to see any usb drive.

Comment: After downloading the extension pack from here ( https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads ), and rebooting, (then selecting "settings">USB>USB3.0),  the problem has finally solved.

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo apt install virtualbox virtualbox-guest-additions-iso (hit enter button)
2. Type your password in the blank space
3. sudo usermod  -a  -G  vboxusers $ USER
4. sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack
5. sudo usermod  -G vboxusers  -a (your host computer name as nick,  Peter etc whatever without brackets)
   Finally reboot your PC and check it finds USB drivers.