# Lost FTDI USB Serial Device after disconnect and reconnect

Tags: usb, virtualbox

VirtualBox 5.1.22, installed extension pack 5.1.22
Win10 host
Ubuntu 16.04 guest, installed 5.1.22 of VirtualBox Guest Additions

Under settings have checked Enable USB Controller, selected USB 2.0 (EHCI) and added my FTDI Quad RS232-HS [0800] filter.

I start Ubuntu. Connect my device. I see my four USB /dev/ttyUSB# serial ports. I can use them just fine.

The problem comes if I remove my USB cable and then re-connect it. When I remove the USB, the ttyUSBs go away as expected. I reconnect the USB cable and the ttyUSBs do not get recreated. I need to restart Ubuntu to get the ports to return.

I have the same VM machine hosted on Win7 under the same VBox configuration and it works. I can connect and reconnect the USB cable over and over and the terminal ports are always recreated.

I tried creating a new Ubuntu guest from scratch (rather than copying the existing one from my Win7 system) and the newly created one has the same problem.

I notice on my Win10 device manager that the Comm Ports are not returned after shutting down Ubuntu.

I'm not sure how to approach solving this issue; is it a hardware issue, a configuration issue with Ubuntu, VB or Win10?! Not sure how to search for answers because it works the first time but fails on retires. I'd be very happy to be pointed to an existing thread or solution.

I'll post a paste from my dmesg below. Perhaps it has a hint? (I am sorry but I can't seem to paste with LFs). The last message shows the usb as recognized attached but nothing further as far as IDing what it is and re-creating the ttyUSBs.

Thanks for taking the time to read this plea.

Mike

```
[   50.582532] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   50.935061] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6011
[   50.935064] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   50.935067] usb 1-1: Product: Quad RS232-HS
[   50.935069] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: FTDI
[   51.006339] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[   51.006347] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[   51.006353] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[   51.023554] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[   51.023589] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
[   51.023606] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   51.023644] usb 1-1: Detected FT4232
[   51.028247] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   51.028261] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   51.028311] usb 1-1: Detected FT4232H
[   51.032871] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[   51.032889] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   51.032927] usb 1-1: Detected FT4232H
[   51.037967] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[   51.037983] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
[   51.038019] usb 1-1: Detected FT4232H
[   51.041199] usb 1-1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB3
[   80.269589] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   80.269806] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[   80.269828] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.0: device disconnected
[   80.272317] ftdi_sio ttyUSB1: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
[   80.272342] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.1: device disconnected
[   80.272659] ftdi_sio ttyUSB2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
[   80.272684] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.2: device disconnected
[   80.273004] ftdi_sio ttyUSB3: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
[   80.273031] ftdi_sio 1-1:1.3: device disconnected
[   89.035073] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
```

Comment: I believe this is very much a Windows 10 issue. Had you tried to remove the USB filter and attach/detach USB devices manually from the virtual machine? What if you detach them before you unplug them?

Comment: Thank you for offering your suggestions. 

If I remove the USB filter and restart the VM Ubuntu guest, the ttyUSBs do not show up at all when I connect the device. They do show up on the Win10 host under the Device Manager (where they come and go as I connect/disconnect/reconnect/..)

I do not know what you mean by 'detach' them. Could you elaborate because I was wondering if there was a proper/safe way of unplugging that I am not following.

Comment: It is from the device menu of the VBox Manager bottom panel: https://askubuntu.com/a/25600/3940

Comment: I see at the bottom right the USB status and it shows the FTDI Quad attached but doesn't allow me to do anything. It appears to be status only. If I remove the VM setting USB filter, than I can see the FTDI device under the Devices->USB and can capture it that way. Then release it as well. But I have the same problem when I try to recapture. I get a dmesg usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
but nothing more, no detection of what the device is, nothing re-attaching it to the ttyUSBs.

Comment: On a fresh connect, the next dmesg I get after
   "usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci"
is
    "usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6011"
but I never get that after a re-connect, and of coarse nothing further.

Comment: That is weird... even more so as you say everything is fine on Windows 7 which makes me believe that it may be some poor handling of these devices from the host Windows 10.

Comment: Agree and I'm not sure where to turn. I just noted another thing, after using Devices->USB to connect and seeing the dmesg abt "new high-seed USB ..", if I do nothing else, then after several minutes VB releases the USB device back to Win10. (the comm ports return to Device Manager and the entry under Devices->USB for the FTDI Quad is again uncheck). To me it points to a VirtualBox issue when VB is running on Win10.

Comment: Just a wild guess: did you try with another USB port? Preferably not USB 3.0.

Comment: Yes and no. I tried a different port but this new computer only has USB3.0 ports. It gets stranger. Sometimes under Devices->USB the line for the FTDI Quad remains after I check it (with a checkbox) which I can come back to and uncheck. Other times, the entire line is no longer listed after I check it. And just now I discovered it randomly worked - once!?! Definitely seems like a VirtualBox issue.

Comment: Only USB3.0? Aaargh... I had similar issues some time ago with USB3.0 ports. Try with enabling USB3.0 support in the guest (needs xHCI from the Oracle extension pack).