# VirtualBox VM can't access USB devices from host

Tags: virtualbox

Guest WIn 10 GUest Addition 5.1.34
Guest Ubuntu 18.04 
Host : Ubuntu 17.10 VB 5.1.34

Trying to access USB devices from the guest VM and can't

Logitech USB HeadSet, USB Stick, Garmin GPS

No USB devices are accessible...

JF

Comment: Did you see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox ?

Comment: I saw that article but I don't have the vboxusers group neither in the Guest or Host VM... I have a vboxsf group