# Ubuntu desktop 18.04.01 and Virtualbox 5.2.18 - How to get the USB stick to work?

Tags: usb, 18.04, virtualbox

I have installed VM's extension pack and guest additions, also in Ubuntu: gnome-system-tools.

This pc is Win10 OS (where to I added VM).

Ubuntu doesn't recognize the USB

Thank you, 
J

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up USB for Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox)