# Virtualbox in sudo mode bad screen after update

Tags: updates, virtualbox, virtualization, screen

After the update to 20.04 LTS when i run the virtualbox in sudo mode the frame/app and the screen of the virtualbox is somehow broken. In the normal mode everything is ok.

[image]

I try re-install the virtualbox but still nothing. Also when You run the VM the screen inside is also broken like in half. Everything else works.

Comment: What is "sudo mode"? Are you running VB with `sudo`? That's a bad idea.

Comment: I didn't ask if its a bad or good. And yes im running sudo as i need to use USB adapters. In the regular mode you can't, you have to have permissions. Or there is another way but that would be different question. The problem is the app screen and the screen of the VM itself.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to use USB adapters. You need VB Extension Pack for that.

Comment: I have that part too. But again let's not go out of the subject and the problem.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). VB is not supposed to be run with `sudo`.

Comment: For USB support see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox/25600#25600. Running VirtualBox with root privileges is not supported in Ubuntu.