# How to write to the attached USB drive from Ubuntu 16.04 in virtual machine

Tags: 16.04, usb-drive

I am wondering how we can detect the USB flash drive in Ubuntu 16.04 which is installed in virtual machibe in Windows 10. Can we directly write data from Ubuntu to USB flash drive ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got the details of your question fully, but I believe you have a Windows host system and a Ubuntu guest. No matter the OS, you will probably need to tell your virtualization software (VirtualBox, VMware, etc) to allow the VM access to the flash drive. This varies depending on your virtualization software, but the links below should help.

- VirtualBox: [How to set up USB for Virtualbox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25596/how-to-set-up-usb-for-virtualbox/25600#25600) (this will vary slightly on a Windows host, mainly in that step two of the accepted answer can be omitted)
- VMware: [Using USB Devices in a Virtual
  Machine](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/devices_usb_ws.html)

If you're not using one of VirtualBox or VMware, or the links don't work for you, please edit your question with details.

Comment: I have https://www.tecmint.com/enable-usb-in-virtualbox/